# Tools to validate JSGF grammar?

Tags: grammar, cmusphinx

What is the best way to validate a [JSGF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSGF) grammar?  I've tried several searches online, and nothing jumps out at me...

Ideally, there is a command line tool like jsonlint for json?

Answer (score 2):

To validate a JSGF file, I just launch pocketsphinx_continuous (from CMU Pocketpshinx) with the JSGF option in a terminal :

```
pocketsphinx_continuous -jsgf my_grammar.jsgf -inmic yes
```

You´ll see if there´s any mistake in your grammar file (syntax error, or if a word is not present in the dictionary). If your file is valid you´ll see "READY...." as the last line in the terminal. Plus, you can then try out your grammar and see if it works (for example, it could be syntactically correct but still have empty speech loops in it that would cause the recognition to fail).

If you´re working with another recognizer from CMU than pocketsphinx, it could still be worth it to install pocketpshinx (you also need sphinxbase) : https://github.com/cmusphinx/pocketsphinx

Otherwise than that I haven´t heard of a pure JSGF validator, and my solution is maybe overkill, but it works.